# How do I connect underground PVC pipe holding wire to rigid conduit?

Tags: wiring, conduit, underground

I am planning to add a (GFCI) receptacle on a fence post, which is 45m from the garage (power feed).  I plan to use NMWU 12/2 cable run in a PVC water pipe (or flexible cable protector) and the risers at both ends will be rigid PVC conduit.  I plan to use 12ga to allow for future extension down the laneway (100m or so).  The 45cm-deep trench will be dug with a mini-ex in an area with no vehicle traffic.  I live in southern Ontario.

**Question:** How is the wire from the ends of the pipe to the conduit to be protected?  (Do I leave it with a small loop or wrap it in something?)

**Edit:** I found a source of flexible PVC electrical conduit, so I can use it and connect the ends to rigid conduit.  (This sort of obviates my question, though.)

Comment: Why are you using cable-in-conduit-and-*pipe*-to-begin-with? This seems like it could be run just as easily with rigid PVC conduit....

Comment: Also, you _cannot_ (in the US, at least) use PVC _water_ supply pipe as electrical _conduit_. Properly rated Schedule 40 _conduit_ is roughly the same price as Schedule 40 _pipe_, so just use the right stuff.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The run is not straight with a few bends around trees and bushes.

Comment: @FreeMan There is a electrical supply house in the nearby town that has flexible PVC electrical conduit rated for burial.

Comment: @Nemo -- how many degrees of bend are needed to make this run to begin with? (Don't want to back you into a corner here when you try to pull thru a run that exceeds the 360deg bend limit in Code)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The entire bend is only 90 degrees but there was a right turn, left turn, right turn, left turn, and a final right turn.

Answer (score 1):

First, apologies for leaving this question for so long and thank you for your comments.

In the end, I used flexible PVC conduit. I could have used rigid conduit, which was less expensive, but decided against it as there were too many elbows to glue (and not all the turns were 90 degrees).  With the flexible conduit, there was only one junction to glue in the middle and the elbows at the end.

Comment: Note that that run is outside of the Code 360deg between pull points bend limit -- see NEC 354.26 and 356.26 for details.  You'll probably need to insert a *handhole* in the middle of the run if you ever go back to it...

Answer (score -1):

usually conduit is used (rigid plastic or metal conduit) not pipe.

Pipe can be used as conduit (if it meets the physical requirements of conduit)  but you'll need to find an appropriate coupling to join your pipe to regulatr electrical fittings.

It may be possible to flare the pipe by heating it until soft and then placing something in the end to stretch it  thus allowing you to join it to some rigid conduit, from there you can use conduit bodies etc, or you may find a pipe that is a good fit in a conduit body, or use a pipe flange to join the pipe to a junction box etc...

Be sure to follow the regulations for burial depth and buried markers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I decided to use flexible conduit.